# PHP mySQL table compare two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need to compare data between two tables.

t1 = playerachievements

| ID | Username | Achievement ID |

t2 = achivements

| ID | Achievement Name | Image Location |

Now I search for items in t1 which match the username of the logged in user

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM playerachievement WHERE username = '$user'";
```

Now what I need to do is grab the Image Location for each achievement the user has based on the Achievement ID in t1 and the ID in t2

What would be the best way to go about this?

### EDIT:

I think I almost have it, however this only brings back one result:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM playerachievement WHERE username = '$user'";

$result = $db_conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $achid = $row['achievement'];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM achievements WHERE id = '$achid'";
    $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<div class='custom-container'>
                        <img src='".$row["image"]."'</img></div>";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: can the player have more than 1 achievement at a time?

Comment: Yes, they can have a whole bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for checking for each value you should give the condition inside `while loop`

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM playerachievement WHERE username = '$user'";
$result1 = $db_conn->query($sql1);
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
 while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $achid = $row1['achievement'];

  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM achievements WHERE id = '$achid'";
  $result2 = $db_conn->query($sql2);
  if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
          while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<div class='custom-container'>
                      <img src='".$row2["image"]."'</img></div>";
          }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, could you give an example?

Comment: i just moved your condition inside your while loop. hope that was the result you expect?

Comment: Ohh, I see now.
That still produces only one result, however it's now prints the first entry instead of the last.

Comment: print your $result->num_rows and check on each queries or update question with sample db

Comment: First returns 3 rows
Second returns 1 row

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your patience on this.